# How to show x axis dates in toast when on click on data point in graph?

Tags: android, graph

I am working on line graphs and it is working fine .
I am using this library : 
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'

I can show the y axis value when i click on the particular data point in the app in Toast. I am using dates in the x axis and want to show dates as well when user click on any data point .But right now it is showing any double value like (1.3455677)

If you see image, Toast message showing two values first x value which should be date as I am using dates in x axis but is showing something else.

[image]

Following is my code

```
 Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d2 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d3 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date d4 = calendar.getTime();

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    GraphView graph1 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    graph.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 50, 0, 200));
    // set manual Y bounds
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(10);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(50);
    graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(d1, 15),
            new DataPoint(d2, 10),
            new DataPoint(d3, 48),
            new DataPoint(d4, 41)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
    series.setTitle("Random Curve 1");
    series.setColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
    series.setDataPointsRadius(15);

    series.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Series1: On Data Point clicked: " + dataPoint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double pointY = dataPoint.getY();
            double pointX = dataPoint.getX();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pointX+" "+pointY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    series.setThickness(8);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show x axis dates in toast when on click on data point in graph you have to do following procedure.

you have to simply convert X axis data into date format.

```
Date d = new java.sql.Date((long) dataPoint.getX());
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa");
String formatted = format1.format(d.getTime());
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, formatted +" "+ dataPoint.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```